# # and ## order of expansion

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

The C standard gives the following example:

```
#define hash_hash # ## #
#define mkstr(a) # a
#define in_between(a) mkstr(a)
#define join(c, d) in_between(c hash_hash d)
char p[] = join(x, y); // equivalent to char p[] = "x ## y";
```

But it also says 'The order of evaluation of # and ## operators is unspecified.'

Why is the expansion of `hash_hash` guaranteed to be interpreted as the ## operator applied to #'s, instead of the # operator applied to ##?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because '#' only acts as an operator if it appears in a function-like macro and is followed by a parameter name ... but hash_hash isn't a function-like macro and those '#' aren't followed by parameter names.

Answer (score 0):

Quote C99:

> A punctuator is a symbol that has independent syntactic and semantic
>   significance. **Depending on context**, it may specify an operation to be
>   performed (which in turn may yield a value or a function designator,
>   produce a side effect, or some combination thereof) in which case it
>   is known as an operator (other forms of operator also exist in some
>   contexts). An operand is an entity on which an operator acts.

`#` and `##` are punctuators.

Besides :

> 6.10.3.1 Argument substitution
>
> After the arguments for the invocation of a function-like macro have been identified, argument
>   substitution takes place. A parameter in the replacement list, unless
>   preceded by a # or ## preprocessing token or followed by a ##
>   preprocessing token (see below), is replaced by the corresponding
>   argument after all macros contained therein have been expanded. Before
>   being substituted, each argument’s preprocessing tokens are completely
>   macro replaced as if they formed the rest of the preprocessing file;
>   no other preprocessing tokens are available.